# Using PayPal Express with Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

PayPal Express is one of the [payment gateways](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways) included in Craft Commerce but I can’t find an example of how to set this up. Is it something that would require a custom plugin for posting secure data to PayPal or is there an easier way to do this out of the box?

I currently have a payment form as per the Commerce example templates with everything working through the Dummy gateway but now looking to replace that form with a simple PayPal Express checkout button, returning to the order page if successful. Any examples or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example templates work with PayPal express out of the box, there is nothing special you need to do.

You can only add PayPal Express as a Payment method when you have bought and registered Craft Commerce.

Paypal Express is an 'offsite' gateway, and it uses the exact same form as the dummy payment form but posts the form without the credit card inputs - that form then redirects you to PayPal.

Comment: All gateways in Commerce 1 are now included by default on install.